# A common technique to reduce the memory requirements for Message Queues?

Tags: operating-system, real-time, computer-science, semaphore, rtos

I'm revising real time operating system schedulers and how Message queues, pipes, Semaphores and Mutex works.

Can anyone provide me with a common technique to reduce the memory requirements for Message Queues in a real-time operating system? I've had a look online but haven't found something useful yet

Thanks

Comment: You might want to flesh this idea out a bit more; otherwise the best you can hope for are sarcastic answers like “send smaller messages”, “send fewer messages”, “have you tried compression”, etc..   Not that I would say any of those things, but there are others who might.

Comment: Well, if you can live with a fixed-size pool queue of message struct/class that is all allocated in an array at startup, contains a one-byte link and you can accept a pool size of 256 or less, then you can get away with any queue requiring only one byte - the index of the first entry in its queue, one semaphore and a mutex (though for performance reasons it's better if you keep an index to both the front and back of the queue).   Just link messages in and out of the queues and the pool as required.